# Cannot change configuration of ElasticBeanstalk environment : "scheduled action(s) are currently associated with this autoscaling group"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I cannot change the configuration of my environment anymore, I'm blocked.

I have an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment with platform Docker.
It is configured to run 1 instance, and has a scheduled action for increasing the number of instances in the morning, and another scheduled action for reverting to one in the evening.
Notice that spot instances are activated ; the first instance is on demand, and any additional instance is a spot instance.

For months, I had no problems. I run my app in production with success.

But now, I want to change the configuration to remove the scheduled actions.

And it fails each time.

What I changed : removing of the scheduled actions and applying the new configuration

[image]

Here are informations from the events (with names anonymized) :

| TIME | TYPE | INFORMATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Octobre 3, 2023 09:14:22 (UTC+2) | INFO | The environment was reverted to the previous configuration setting. |
| Octobre 3, 2023 09:14:06 (UTC+2) | ERROR | Failed to deploy configuration. |
| Octobre 3, 2023 09:14:06 (UTC+2) | ERROR | Updating Auto Scaling group named: xxxxxx failed Reason: Autoscaling rolling updates cannot be performed because scheduled action(s) [zzzzzz] are currently associated with this autoscaling group; either delete these actions or suspend the ScheduledActions process and then retry the update. |
| Octobre 3, 2023 09:14:05 (UTC+2) | ERROR | Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'yyyyyy' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: null |
| Octobre 3, 2023 09:13:49 (UTC+2) | INFO | Updating environment xxxxxx's |
| Octobre 3, 2023 09:13:41 (UTC+2) | INFO | Environment update is starting. |